# Type signature for type class function to allow customized SQL queries in a Yesod subsite

Tags: haskell, yesod

The aim is to allow customized SQL queries in a Yesod subsite that can be executed in the same runDB transaction initiated in the subsite handler.

```
postSubSiteHandler :: forall master. (SubSiteInterface master, YesodAuthPersist master, KeyEntity (AuthId master) ~ User, YesodPersistBackend master ~ SqlPersistT)
    lift $ runDB do
        {- ... subsite-related queries ... -}
        customQueries
```

If I include the definition of `customQueries` in the subsite, ghc provides the type signature `forall (m :: * -> *). (MonadResource m, MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadLogger m) => SqlPersistT m()`.

However, the definition of `customQueries` should be provided outside the subsite in an instance of `SubSiteInstance`.

An attempt to declare `customQueries` follows:

```
class Yesod master => SubSiteInterface master where
    customQueries :: forall (m :: * -> *). 
                    (MonadResource m, MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadLogger m,
                     YesodPersistBackend master ~ SqlPersistT) =>
                     SqlPersistT m ()
```

The declaration above does not work. It gives the following error message when the module containing the handler is compiled:

```
Could not deduce (YesodPersistBackend master0 ~ SqlPersistT)
from the context (SubSiteInterface master, 
                  KeyEntity (AuthId master) ~ User,
                  YesodPersistBackend master ~ SqlPersistT)
```

How should the type signature of `customQueries` be modified to unify the type variables `master` and `master0`?

Comment: Does `SqlPersistT (HandlerT master IO)` work?